# Automatic widening in frama-c value analysis

Tags: c, frama-c, abstract-interpretation

I am looking for a method to perform widening on loops with no user hints.
I'll explain using an example:

```
int z;
void main(void) {   
    int r = Frama_C_interval(0, MAX_INT);
    z = 0;
    for (int y=0; y<r; y++)
        z++;
}
```

When running frama-c value analysis on this code, the global variable *z* receives the interval [--,--]. Because z was set to zero and the loop consists of an incremental operator, an automatic widening method should be able to deduct that the more accurate interval is [0, --].
Is it possible to do this in Frama-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When running frama-c value analysis on this code, the global variable z receives the interval [--,--].

No it doesn't:

```
~ $ frama-c -version ; echo
Magnesium-20151001+dev
~ $ cat t.c
#define MAX_INT 0x7fffffff

int z;
void main(void) {   
    int r = Frama_C_interval(0, MAX_INT);
    z = 0;
    for (int y=0; y<r; y++)
        z++;
}
~ $ frama-c -val t.c
…
t.c:8:[kernel] warning: signed overflow. assert z+1 ≤ 2147483647;
…
[value] Values at end of function main:
  z ∈ [0..2147483647]
…
```

This is a development version, but the same should apply to any version since signed overflow started to be treated as a serious error with ACSL alarm. If you are using a version from when signed overflow was assumed to harmlessly produce 2's complement results, 1) you should upgrade, it has been years and 2) `z` can hardly be argued to be trivially positive then (although it is positive because of a relational invariant linking the values of `z` and `y` while the loop is executing, relational invariant that the value analysis cannot represent).